# How to use Jest moduleNameMapper with NestJS, when in tsconfig I have a generic path (*)?

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

Sorry, I know that the title may be very confusing. I could not find a better way to put it. But the situation is that I don't know of a way to construct my `moduleNameMapper` in the Jest config, because I couldn't find an example for my specific case.

I've seen examples like `"^src/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1"` and `"@alias/*": [ 'path/to/alias/*' ]` etc.

I have a `tsconfig` with following `baseUrl` and `paths`:

```json
"baseUrl": "src",
"paths": {
  "*": ["domain/*", "*"]
},
```

But I don't know how to reflect this in my `moduleNameMapper`. I have tried `"src/(.*)$": ["<rootDir>/domain/$1", "<rootDir>/$1"]` and also altered the beginning part to `"src/(.*)"`, `"@/(.*)"`, `"/(.*)"`, `"(.*)"` `"*"` but none of them work. Would there be a solution to this case?

I also tried to solve this a long time ago, and remember not being able to use `pathsToModuleNameMapper` from **ts-jest**, it also did not work. And it also seems that NestJS currently does not support Vitest, if I'm not mistaken.

Thanks in advance, and best regards.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? I am using `jest` with `ts-jest` in a `nestjs` project with no problem. Please add your aim so maybe there is another solution other than using `moduleNameMapper`

Comment: I was trying to run the basic tests and that Jest would understand the path resolution. As I'm using the dynamic paths (both absolute and relative). But soon I'll try again with ts-jest, to have the paths mapped automatically. And then update here in any case, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that Jest cannot understand this "generic" path, as its way of resolving the paths is different from the tsconfig setting.

There are two problems:

- The path doesn't have something that distinguishes it, as it means anything, represented by the star (*). Jest will put any import into this rule and will therefore fail.
- In order to use many path patterns under a single alias, it would be necessary to use a Jest Resolver, which I did implement to see how it would go, but didn't like the result. As I would lose the `pathsToModuleNameMapper` functionality, and want to have this automated for me.

In the end, I just altered the `paths` in `tsconfig` to the same thing, just a bit more "ugly" and explicit.

```json
"paths": {
  "users/*": ["domain/users/*"],
  "clients/*": ["domain/clients/*"],
  // ...
},
```

And that's it. With this I can use a `jest.config.js` file and add to it

```js
modulePaths: ['<rootDir>'],
moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, {
  prefix: '<rootDir>',
}),
```

I think this is best option currently available, in order to solve this matter.

Comment: I think it's possible now using regular expressions. Something like `'^users/(.*)': '<rootDir>/domain/users/$1.ts'`.  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring